# install sql server drivers for php

Tags: php, sql-server

hello everybody I'm new to coding world and I need your help I would like to connect to a server with xampp (3.2.2)  and php version (7.2.4) windows 10... I have installed the drivers php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll and php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll to php.ini but also to php\ext

and when I am trying to connect to a server with this code doesn't respond
thank you very much for your time

```
$servename = "new";
$username = "user";
$password = "tree";
$database = "tree";
$connectionInfo =array("Database" =>"tree","USER" => "user", "PWD" => "tree");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($servename,$connectionInfo);
if($conn)
    {echo"connection established";}
else
    {echo"connection failure";die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));}
```

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Comment: Please add the error to your main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use it with help of PDO,
Please check below code and try to replace with your original data

```
<?php 

    $dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=**servernamehere**;Database=**Db name here**";
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, "", "");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    } 

    ?>
```

Comment: it worked thank you so much...but can you tell a few resources where i can find to learn coding on php and sql server because i'm familiar only with my sql and php myadmin

Comment: If the answer is working for you then please accept as an answer so am able to help others.

Comment: Please use CI or some different Framework like Laravel with PHP so u can directly access it's inbuilt functionality with connect to MSSQL(you need to to change only database connectivity).
It's save your time for learn PDO from start and make queries for it.

Comment: actually i just add in to xamp the sqlsrv .dll and i dont have any problem with the database connectivity..but i will try to follow your advice...can you tell me 2 or 3 sites where i can be better at programming in php...thank you very much for your help